# Compiling binary using dynamic libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking

I have 20 shared objects files, and I want to use one function from the let`s say "a.so"
but my problem is that a.so is linked to other libraries.
When i compile my main  i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: b.so, needed by /home/test/lib/a.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: c.so, needed by /home/test/lib/a.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

How can i compile my main that i would be able to use the function in a.so ?
I have tried to use this method: `gcc -L. -WL, -rpath,. main.c -l{libraryName}  -o main`
but i get the following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-WL,’; did you mean ‘-Wa,’?
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath,.’
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i compile my main i get the following error:

There are two mistakes in above statement:

- you get a *warning*, not an error, and
- you get it when you *link* your program, not when you compile it.

> How can i compile my main that i would be able to use the function in a.so ?

Like so:

```
gcc -L. -Wl,-rpath=. main.c -l{libraryName} -o main
```

P.S. In general, it's a bad practice to have `-rpath` as a relative path, because the program will not work if you invoke it from a different directory. A better solution is to use absolute `-rpath` instead:

```
gcc -L/home/test/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/test/lib main.c -l{libraryName} -o main
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath=/home/test/lib'

Comment: @alpico You are right: new version of GCC reject the "bare" `-rpath`. I've updated the answer.